# I created HighStockChart Graph in .Net MVC but Y-axis label is coming in right side but i want it to be appeard on left side

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts

[image]

Hi,
I tried with Opposite=true or false, but then also Y-axis label is not coming in left side Please suggest any solution that will be highly appreciated.

and coding we did is:

```
highChart.Credits.Enabled = false;
            highChart.Title = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.Title
            {
                Text = ""
            };
            highChart.Subtitle = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.Subtitle
            {
                Text = ""

            };
            highChart.Exporting = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.Exporting { Enabled = false };
            highChart.YAxis = new List<Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.YAxis>
                {
                    new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.YAxis()
                    {

                        Title = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.YAxisTitle
                        {
                            Text="Price GBP",

                        },
                       LineColor = "#fff",
                       Labels = new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.YAxisLabels {Align = YAxisLabelsAlign.Center},
                        Opposite=true
                    },
                };

            highChart.RangeSelector = new RangeSelector()
            {

                Selected = 5,
                InputEnabled = false,
                Enabled = false
            };
            highChart.Chart.Height = 745;
            highChart.Series = new List<Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.Series>
                {
                    new Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Stocks.AreaSeries
                    {
                       Data = ViewData["appleData"] as List<AreaSeriesData> ,

                        Name = "AAPL",
                        GapSize = 5,

                        Tooltip = new AreaSeriesTooltip
                        {
                            ValueDecimals = 2,
                            PointFormatter= "function() { return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y',this.x) + ','+this.y +''; }",

                        },
                        TurboThreshold = null,
                        FillColor = "#12a7bd",

                    }
                };
            fundDetailsModel.NetAssetNew = string1.GetHighstock(highChart, "highstock");
```